# How do I find a basis for the null space of the linear functional given below?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

$x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and $f(x) = a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + a_3 x_3$, $a_1 \not=0$.

I worked on a similar problem where $f(x) = x_1 + x_2 - x_3$ and the basis for $N(f)$ was easily found to be $(1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1)$. I'm not getting the same answer as the book for the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely you get the same answer as the book, because the null space of the functional has infinitely many bases and one is as good as any other.

The equation defining the null space is
$$
a_1x_1=-a_2x_2-a_3x_3
$$
so you get a basis by first assigning $x_2=1$, $x_3=0$ and then $x_2=0$ and $x_3=1$. So a basis is
$$
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{a_2}{a_1}\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{a_3}{a_1}\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
but you can also assign first $x_2=-a_1$, $x_3=0$ and then $x_2=0$, $x_3=-a_1$, getting as basis
$$
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
a_2\\
-a_1\\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
a_3\\
0\\
-a_1
\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
There is no “canonical” choice. You can assign any pair of values to $x_2$ and $x_3$, say first $x_2=a$, $x_3=c$ and then $x_2=b$ and $x_3=d$ so long as the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has rank two.

The first choice corresponds to the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the second one corresponds to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-a_1 & 0\\
0 & -a_1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You know that $f(x) = 0$ **iff** $x_1 = -{1 \over a_1} (a_2 x_2 + a_3 x_3)$.

So you can choose $x_2,x_3$ arbitrarily and find the corresponding $x_1$.

Comment: Yes, but the back of the book says the basis is $(a_2, -a_1, 0), (a_3, 0, -a_1)$. How are they getting that?

Comment: If I choose $x_2=1, x_3 = 0$ then you must have $x_1 = -{a_2 \over a_1}$, that is $(-{a_2 \over a_1},1, 0)$. You can take any non zero  element of the span, so multiply by $-a_1$ to get $(a_2, -a_1, 0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same idea.  Your subspace is that of all vectors $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ such that $a_1x_1+ a_2x_2+ a_3x_3= 0$.  So we can write $x_3= -\frac{a_1x_1+ a_2x_2}{a_3}$.  Then $(x_1, x_2, x_3)= (x_1, x_2, -\frac{a_1x_1+ a_2x_2}{a_3})$= $(x_1, 0, -\frac{a_1}{a_3}x_1)+ (0, x_2, -\frac{a_2}{a_3}x_2)$= $x_1(1, 0, -\frac{a_1}{a_3})+ x_2(0, 1,-\frac{a_2}{a_3})$.